# How to resolve hidden form field auto generated from @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Whenever i create a boolean property in my ASP.NET MVC model and try to create a checkbox using @Html.CheckBoxFor i get a hidden form field autogenerated. I know it is happening for a good reason but whenever i submit my form and get that value using form collection it returns 2 values when it is in checked state. It submits value like this - 'true,false'. Now when i get the values using form collection and do bool.Parse() it throws an error because it cannot parse 'true,false' together. Is there any way around to get rid of hidden form field or should i try something while processing the request ??

In Model

```
[Display(Name ="Is Enabled")]
public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult Request(FormCollection collection) 
{
   bool valueIsEnabled=bool.Parse(collection["IsEnabled"])                  
}
```

In View

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsEnabled, new { 
   @class = "custom-input"
})
```

When I click Checked

Expected Result - true
Actual Result - true,false

When I don't click checked

Expected Result - false
Actual Result - false

Comment: Try changing the name of the property I think its clashing some where.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue is not with Name. HTML is generated like this for hidden field <input name="IsEnabled" type="hidden" value="false">

Comment: Did you try changing it?

Comment: I had tried that :)

Comment: I faced the same problem. I created customer HTML MVC Helper for that.
You may refer this site: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3194c4/custom-html-helpers-in-mvc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I did some research and found that the CheckBox helper generates an additional hidden field with the same name as the checkbox (you can see it by browsing the generated source code):

```
<input checked="checked" id="Visible" name="Visible" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Visible" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

So both values are sent to the controller action when you submit the form. Here's a comment directly from the ASP.NET MVC source code explaining the reasoning behind this additional hidden field:

```
if (inputType == InputType.CheckBox) {
    // Render an additional <input type="hidden".../> for checkboxes. This
    // addresses scenarios where unchecked checkboxes are not sent in the request.
    // Sending a hidden input makes it possible to know that the checkbox was present
    // on the page when the request was submitted.
    ...
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Thank you :) . But is there any way to work with FormCollection ? Please let me know if you have any solution for that ?

Comment: @Varun I have added another approach in my answer, I hope it helps. Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: No, I think you can remove this approach and then I can mark your answers as most suitable for this problem.

Comment: The most suitable approach for this approach was model binding, it is not working correctly for form collection. But for now I can accept the answer with model binding.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "CheckBox helper generates an additional hidden field with the same name as the checkbox" Actually it adds the same name as it can guess from the asp-for attribute. If you have a custom name attribute for the input with the asp-for attribute, the hidden input will still have the original attribute's name. This way the hidden checkbox won't work